# Precompiling assets failed. - SOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
****ERROR MESSAGE******
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        LoadError: cannot load such file -- yui/compressor
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/autoload/yui.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:39:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:24:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:24:in `instance'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_2693109f145a888e2c997888081094e8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

---

I havent been able to deploy to Heroku since i created this repo?
Any theories?

Putted this on my config/application.rb (based on another post) but it didnt work:
    require_relative 'boot'

```
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.enter code here
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Bgwsite
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true

    config.generators do |generate|
          generate.assets false
          generate.helper false
          generate.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: false
        end
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

Comment: Post the error message you are getting when you try to deploy

Comment: @MarkMerrit this is the error:

Comment: remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed

Comment: Please put the error message into your question and not in the comments ;)

Comment: @Capricorn did you see the error? I thought it was webpack but it didnt work - I ran webpack-dev-server but nothing...